# How to perform tf.nn.softmax in two selected dimension in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, softmax

I want to implement the `tf.nn.softmax()` for the selected two dimension of a tensor with shape `(batch_size=?, height, width, channel)`.

But it seems not possible for `tf.nn.softmax()` to receive 2 axis in the same time. Using `tf.softmax(tensor, axis=[1, 2])` will raise axis error in tensorflow.

How can I implement this elegantly and in vectorized mode? thx :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing two dimensions at a time, I would first reshape the input accordingly, e.g.:

```
array = tf.constant([[1., 2.], [3., 4.]])

tf.nn.softmax(array, axis=0) # Calculate for axis 0
tf.nn.softmax(array, axis=1) # Calculate for axis 1

tf.nn.softmax(tf.reshape(array, [-1])) # Calculate for both axes
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with keras activation functions:

```
# logits has shape [BS, H, W, CH]
prob = tf.keras.activations.softmax(logits, axis=[1, 2])
# prob has shape [BS, H, W, CH]
check = tf.reduce_sum(prob, axis=[1, 2])
# check is tensor of ones with shape [BS, CH]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
array = np.random.rand(1, 2, 2, 1)
s1 = tf.nn.softmax(array, axis=1)
s2 = tf.nn.softmax(array, axis=2)
rs = tf.reduce_sum([s1, s2], 0)
```

This will return tensor of same shape as initial array

Comment: Yes, but it will not ensure that the sum of all the elements in the array is 1, which is an important consideration given that softmax if often used to interpret the outputs as probabilities.